# UITextView's not displaying content during push animation when is in inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UIViewController` that has `inputAccessoryView` overrided with custom `UITextView`, lets call that view controller A. And I have another view controller that push A to navigation stack.

So, when I push A first time everything is ok - the `UITextView` appeared with text immediately. The strange thing starts with next push - the `UITextView`'s text does not appear until view controller push transition animation end.

[image: During animation] =>
[image: Animation completed]

The code of viewController A is there:

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    private var userInputView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero,
            size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30)
        ), textContainer: nil)
        textView.text = "asd"

        userInputView = textView
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return userInputView
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Tested in iOS 9.3 simulator.

After some coding I noticed that if `inputAccessoryView` is not deallocated (stored somewhere in global scope) the appearance during animation <s>is defined by last `UITextView` state. But this solution is not good for me</s> is ok actually. But is there any native-like solution, am I missing something? Because the desired behaviour is rather standard in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will stick with the solution where the `inputAccessoryView` is stored until next appearance.

Comment: I have the same strange behavior with that not showing text. How did you solve this?